# Can VB.net UI(Front end) be joined with Java Backend

Tags: java, vb.net

I have a User interface in VB.net(for a desktop application). And i want the backend to be in Java.

How to connect them .
[image: VB.net UI]

Example: I want to have the search box functionality to be wriiten in Java.

Comment: Though this pretty much a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152967/can-you-use-java-libraries-in-a-vb-net-program).

Comment: @pickypg Not really, this question asked about the use of a backend, the question you linked to wanted to share libraries.

Comment: @Darryl Braaten Backend or not, a Java library is going to be called the same way. For what it's worth, I do think a Web Service is the best and easiest route given the above UI.

Comment: Apart from webservices are there any other ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.  The easiest way would be to implement your backend as web services.