# JTAPI (Avaya) with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jtapi

I was wondering if somebody could answer my questions as I have not used JTAPI before.

I am working on a project where the requirement is to click a link on the MVC website and integrate the call to AVAYA phone (i.e. make phone call using handset via the website)

I have also looked at the Microsoft TAPI but looks like there is no integration with Avaya available with TAPI.

Does anybody know how can I use JTAPI with .Net MVC ? I was assuming it would be an API which I can call from my website but it looks more complicated then it sounds.

Please suggest :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use Avaya DMCC. It has an implementation for .NET

But beware the Avaya licensing policy! DMCC may require extra licenses.

To use JTAPI from ASP.NET you have to use Java classes from .NET

- [Can you use Java libraries in a VB.net program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152967/can-you-use-java-libraries-in-a-vb-net-program)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13549/Using-Java-Classes-in-your-NET-Application

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have another question based on your reply and would appreciate if you can throw some light please.

1) Would it be possible to call the JTAPI API directly from >NET by just renaming JTAPI.jar to JTAPI.dll?

2) Is it true I can only use the bridge to link java api to .net if it is a desktop application?

Comment: 1) No! 2) I've never used any .NET-JAVA bridge, so the answer is : I don't know. I just know that there is something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create an Applet in JTAPI and then integrate in any webapplication whether php,.net I recently did the same thing for my PHP web application.

Answer (score 0):

As @Krishna said with an Applet you could designe your solución, designe that i used to do... Buut now and Day Applets have less support over browsers and they have be come a problem than a solution. The way that i found to solve this issue was use **HTML5** with **Websocket**. In this way i create a Windows Service or daemon (for Linux) to handle JTapi session and create a websocket server Layer, and implement the websocket to create the view int he Asp.net view.

Answer (score 0):

Avaya AES does expose a basic web api providing some basic functionalities which you can call directly from your MVC application, but if you need something more advance, then arguably the best solution would be to build a small Java servlet which you will host on something like Tomcat or JBoss which will expose a SOAP or REST API, which you can call from your MVC app.