# how to call OWL API from vb.net.I would like to run SWRL rules uppn OWL ontology

Tags: vb.net, jar, owl, owl-api, swrlapi

I would like to run SWRL rules uppn OWL ontology and use the results in my VB.NET (web base).
I downloaded OWL API (a jar file)from http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/ but in the documentation I could not find how to call this jar file from vb.net .

can you help on this??
please

Answer (score 0):

This has the same answer as [Can you use Java libraries in a VB.net program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152967/can-you-use-java-libraries-in-a-vb-net-program)

OWLAPI is a java library; in order to use it from another programming language, what's required is the ability of that language to interface with Java.

I do not have VB.net experience, but if it's possible to interface with Java at all then it's possible to use OWLAPI the same way.

Comment: hi dear ignazio.   do you have some experince or some source code with .net like c# regarding this issue . because i can convert c# to vb.net if you have sample for that.  i would appreciate if you can help me on that.

Comment: I don't but check the answers on the question I linked, there are examples and projects linked.

Comment: they said it can not be done .they said i need to know j# . but i know just vb,net asp.net and sql server

Comment: i installed netbeans and  i tried to work with netbeans . but still i could not find any good information how to  work with OWL and SWRL with net beans .do you have some source code related to it? please

Comment: OWLAPI tutorials are available here: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation

Comment: ok but seems it just can be work with netbeans not with vb.net..  so do i need to switch to netbeans ???

Comment: Of course it can be used from any Java IDE. Netbeans, Intellij or Eclipse can all be used.